# How to set up a global variable accessible across all pages of asp.net core razor app

Tags: asp.net-core

I have developed a simple asp.net core razor app with Windows authentication to be used in our intranet, hosted on prem.

In order to distinguish a normal user from admin user (the the user who is allowed CRUD), I check for the logged in user principal against the AD group member. I have a static helper function which does that.

At the moment I use a public flag on each page by calling that helper function, to be used in the razor page to show/hide the edit/delete buttons.

Is it possible to run this function only once (say, in the index page) and set a global flag to be used across all pages?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a cache server to store the data fetched in the static helper function.

Of course, from your current design, the least code change is to use redis cache. Then inject the middleware of redis cache into Controller or Razor Page.

---

If global variables are used in .net core, an object can be set when the program is initialized to store userid and read-write permission. But when running the static helper function, the data may not be dynamic and real-time. So I think the design might be flawed.

---

But I think you should use [Role-Based authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-6.0) in your project. Because you also use Azure AAD. So I recommend you to read the article below.

[IMPLEMENT APP ROLES AUTHORIZATION WITH AZURE AD AND ASP.NET CORE （Microsoft MVP's Blog）](https://damienbod.com/2021/02/01/implement-app-roles-authorization-with-azure-ad-and-asp-net-core/)

Comment: Thanks Jason. All this redis cache etc. seems like an overkill for what I am trying to accomplish; I am not a professional web developer and it's not a high profile project, instead a simple web application to be used internally in our team. In order to dabble with web development, I took up learning asp.net core razor pages app  in the last few weeks using this internal app as a starting point. I guess for now I will use the per page admin check to accomplish what I need to. Thanks again.

Comment: I managed to resolve my issue in the end using asp.net core session. I check if the user is admin (i.e. whether user is a member of the group) in index page model and set it in session variable and retrieve it in all other pages where I need to check.

TempData would have been alternate option but I would need to explicitly keep/seek to retain the value in every page after accessing it, so felt Session is a better alternative.

May be query string was another option but that's too old school and ugly to look at :-)